# How to capture corresponding close price at successive pivot highs or pivot lows of RSI?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying with below code to capture corresponding close price at successive pivot highs or pivot lows of RSI. However, it doesn't seem to capture the close price. What am I missing?

```
rsi = rsi(close, 14)

plr = pivotlow(rsi, 5, 5)

p1 = valuewhen(plr, close, 0)
p2 = valuewhen(plr[1], close, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rsi = rsi(close, 14)

plr = pivotlow(rsi, 5, 5)

getloc(bar_i)=>
    _ret = bar_index + 5 - bar_i 
    
pos = valuewhen(plr, bar_index, 0)
val = nz(close[getloc(pos)])
```

this might work (untested)